# How to run docker image , take ssh of container and bind port to "49" in single cmd?

Tags: bash, docker, ssh, dockerfile, docker-machine

I wanted to run the image and take the `ssh (bin/bsh)` of container at the same time. 
To start a container and take ssh

```
docker run -i -t --entrypoint /bin/bash <Image ID>
```

But in above cmd, I am not able to bind port to 49.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Can you please clarify what you mean with "take ssh", and why/how you want to "bind port to 49"? Which port do you want to bind to 49? And what is the image that you're looking to start?

Comment: I also don't get your "take ssh", but you can bind ports from your container with the `-d` flag, like `docker run -p 49:22 -it <image> bash`, [see here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it.

```
docker run -p 8046:49 -i -t --entrypoint /bin/bash [Image Id]
```

Above command start the container from image , bind port "**8046**" to service running on port "**49**" and also give you terminal of that image.

Thanks for all yours comment.